How do I get my signal handler to catch a signal sent by a child process?
I'm writing a very basic shell in C with some basic job control. If the user enters a non-built in command, then the parent forks and creates a child then the child can execute a program.
I have signal handlers to handle SIGCHLD, SIGINT, and SIGTSTP. These handlers are able to catch signals sent by the terminal (i.e. if I press ctrl+z then the termial sends SIGTSTP and the SIGTSTP signal is caught by my sigtstp_handler).
But I need the handler to also catch a signal sent by a child process, i.e. if the child executes a program like ./prog and in prog is an instruction "kill(prog_pid, SIGTSTP)", then I need my sigtstp_handler to catch that signal.
So for example, here's my sigtstp_handler:
void sigtstp_handler(int sig) 
{
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = fgpid(jobs)) > 0) { //make sure foreground job exists
        kill(-pid, SIGTSTP);
        printf("caught SIGTSTP");
    }
    
    return;
}

Then my main function basically (cutting a lot out since its too long) looks like:
main() {
   Signal(SIGTSTP, sigtstp_handler); //install sigtstp_handler
   
   if ((output = builtin_cmd(argv)) == 0) {
        sigset_t mask, prev_mask;
        sigemptyset(&mask);
        sigaddset(&mask, SIGTSTP);

        //block signal
        sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &prev_mask);
     
        pid = fork();
        //CHILD 
        if (pid == 0) {
            //unblock signal for child
            sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &prev_mask, NULL); 
            
            setpgid(0,0); //set pgid
                        
            //run user program
            if (execve(argv[0], argv, environ) < 0) { //
                printf("Command not found\n");
                exit(0);
            } 
        }
        //PARENT
        if (pid != 0){ 
            addjob(pid);

            //unblock signals for parent
            sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &prev_mask, NULL);

            if (!background) {     
                waitfg(pid); 
            }  
        }
    }

    return;
}

So sigtstp_handler catches my signal if its sent from the terminal by ctrl+z. But it does not catch it if it was sent by a child process via kill(pid, SIGTSTP) (and I know it doesn't catch it because it doesn't do the print statement).
Why is it not catching the signal from a child process? I thought that when I install the handler, it basically makes it so anytime a SIGTSTP signal is sent, instead of doing whatever the default is, it executes my handler. So shouldn't it catch SIGTSTP no matter what it comes from? I'm having the same trouble with my sigint_handler not catching SIGINT when it comes from a child process.
And how can I make sure it does catch that signal?
I'm thinking maybe its a problem with my signal blockers? So I block SIGTSTP in the parent, then I fork. Then in the child I unblock all signals then run a program. So the signals are unblocked when the child proces calls kill(). And in the parent I add the job, then unblock, then wait for a foreground process to finish. But the parent can accept SIGCHILD signals just fine, so I don't know why it would be blocking the signal from kill().
I also know (at least an pretty sure) its not a problem with my signal handler only acting on a foreground process because its a foreground process that calls kill(pid, SIGTSTP).
I appreciate any help.

Tangential comments — Note that error messages should be printed on stderr, not stdout.  If the execve() call succeeds, it doesn't return; if it returns, it failed.  There is no need to test the value it returns.  When you exit after execve() returns, it is not appropriate to exit with status 0 — that indicates success.

kill(-pid, SIGTSTP);  Is that - intended?

Note that when a process is executed, the ignored signals continue to be ignored, but all handled signals are reset to the default state (see POSIX execve()).  Think about it: the address of a signal handler in the executed process is unrelated to the address of any signal handlers in the previous process, so it makes no sense to keep the signal handlers.  The new process must set its own signal handlers.

@EugeneSh. Probably. A negative PID means to send to the entire process group.

Note that main() { is not valid C99, let alone C17 (or C23) — you must specify the return type.  You should normally use int main(void) if you ignore command-line arguments.  Also, the return; at the end of main() should be return 0; or something similar.  Even under the C90 rules, the function should return a value as the type is implicitly int.  (You could omit the return altogether under C99 or later rules, and that's equivalent to adding return 0;, but I think that rule is an abomination.)

The parent process doesn't receive signals sent to the child. When the child stops due to receiving a SIGTSTP signal, the parent receives a SIGCHLD signal, and the data returned by wait() will indicate that the child was stopped. This is how shells print "[PID] Stopped".

When you implement job control, the process running the program shouldn't be in the same process group as the shell. So sending the signal to -pid will not signal the shell.

Signal(SIGTSTP, sigtstp_handler);?!?? Signal()???  First, please your actual code.  Second, use sigaction() and not signal()  Third, do not call non-async-signal-safe functions such as printf() in a signal handler.

@JonathanLeffler My bad, the part of the code that is forks is part of a different void function which main calls, so theres no error with the return type. By "the new process must set its own signal handlers", do you mean it can't use the signal handlers in my shell.cc program? So the prog.cc program would need to have its own signals?

@Barmar That makes sense I think. I do have a sigchild_handler which will check if the child was stopped. So only sigchild signals can be sent from a child process to the parent? And so I if the child process doesn't have its own handler (like Jonathan said), I can only handle a stopped signal that was sent by a child process with my sigchild handler?

The child can send any signals it wants, with kill(getppid(), SIGWHATEVER). But only SIGCHLD is sent automatically, when certain things happen to the child.

@wofster The child can't use the parent's handlers after it calls exec(), since those signal functions don't exist in the child process any more.

@Barmar More precisely: "Signals set to be caught by the calling process image shall be set to the default action in the new process image"

OT: setpgid(0,0); //set pgid?  That comment is worse than useless.  First, it merely repeats what the code already shows that it's doing.  Second, what is pgid?  The comment is no help with that if someone doesn't know. Third, if the function call is changed to, say setuid() and the comment is missed, it's now wrong - for a comment that literally adds no information.  And as a matter of style, comments placed to the right of code are harder to maintain, especially if you take lots of time to line them all up so they're pretty.  Those kind of comments are an utter pain to update.

You have to install signal handlers specifically for the child process. As Barmar mentions in the comments:

The parent process doesn't receive signals sent to the child. When the child stops due to receiving a SIGTSTP signal, the parent receives a SIGCHLD signal, and the data returned by wait() will indicate that the child was stopped.

and:

The child can't use the parent's handlers after it calls exec(), since those signal functions don't exist in the child process any more.

According to the man page:

Signals set to the default action (SIG_DFL) in the calling process image shall be set to the default action in the new process image. Except for SIGCHLD, signals set to be ignored (SIG_IGN) by the calling process image shall be set to be ignored by the new process image. Signals set to be caught by the calling process image shall be set to the default action in the new process image (see <signal.h>).
If the SIGCHLD signal is set to be ignored by the calling process image, it is unspecified whether the SIGCHLD signal is set to be ignored or to the default action in the new process image.

Some other things you should note:

The return type of main(). As Jonathan Leffer mentions in the comments:


Note that main() { is not valid C99, let alone C17 (or C23) — you must specify the return type. You should normally use int main(void) if you ignore command-line arguments. Also, the return; at the end of main() should be return 0; or something similar. Even under the C90 rules, the function should return a value as the type is implicitly int. (You could omit the return altogether under C99 or later rules, and that's equivalent to adding return 0;, but I think that rule is an abomination.)


printf() is async-signal-unsafe. Calling it in a signal handler has undefined behavior according to both the POSIX Standard and the C standard. Though, POSIX specifies write() to be async-signal-safe, and that can be used in a signal handler.

About Signal(SIGTSTP, sigtstp_handler); //install sigtstp_handler, there is no such thing as Signal, unless you've defined it as a wrapper around the signal() call. According to the man page for signal():



The only portable use of signal() is to set a signal's disposition to SIG_DFL or SIG_IGN.

Replace it with sigaction().
